# radio button form to print text

Tags: forms, radio-button

Help.  I'm not a programmer, but a historian.  I'm trying to create a radio button form so that when I click on the buttons of the form, in different sub-groups, then hit submit, I get a text box with the text of radio button selections.

Here's what I have so far.  What I need is java code that allows the printing.  Hopefully people can figure out what I'm trying to do and help.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Paper Comments</TITLE>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript">


    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>


<BODY>

    <FORM NAME="frmOne" ACTION="" METHOD="POST">

    <P>

<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="thesis4"> Thesis is explicit and     clear<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="thesis3"> Thesis is clear<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="thesis2">Thesis unclear but decipherable<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="thesis1"> Thesis is vague<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="thesis0"> No Thesis<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="thesisnone"> Answer this question here.  The answer would be the thesis.<br>

</P>    
<P>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value=“intro4”> Introduction provides direction<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value=“intro3”> Introduction provides some direction <br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value="intro2">Introduction provides little direction<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name=“intro” Value="intro1">Introduction provides no direction<br></P>


    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  SUBMIT  " onClick="validate()">
    </FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Paper Comments</TITLE>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript">

function validate(){
var radios = document.getElementsByName('thesis');
var tarea=document.getElementById('ta');
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
       tarea.innerHTML=radios[i].value+"\n";
        break;
    }
}
radios = document.getElementsByName('intro');
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        tarea.innerHTML+=radios[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
}
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>


<BODY>

    <FORM NAME="frmOne">

    <P>

<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="Thesis is explicit and clear"> Thesis is explicit and     clear<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="Thesis is clear"> Thesis is clear<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="Thesis unclear but decipherable">Thesis unclear but decipherable<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="Thesis is vague"> Thesis is vague<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="No Thesis"> No Thesis<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="thesis" Value="Answer this question here.  The answer would be the thesis."> Answer this question here.  The answer would be the thesis.<br>

</P>    
<P>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value="Introduction provides direction"> Introduction provides direction<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value="Introduction provides some direction"> Introduction provides some direction <br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value="Introduction provides little direction">Introduction provides little direction<br>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="intro" Value="Introduction provides no direction">Introduction provides no direction<br></P>


    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  SUBMIT  " onClick="validate()">

    </FORM>
    Your Selection:
<TEXTAREA id="ta"></textarea>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot.  How do I make the text box bigger?

Comment: <textarea id="ta" rows="4" cols="50">. You can increase or decrease size with `rows` or `cols` attribute. Mark it as the answer if the problem is solved..

Comment: It's almost working.  When I click on the radio buttons and hit "submit," the full statement under "thesis" shows up (ex: Thesis is clear), but the next line only has "Introduction.  So, there's an unwanted " and only the first word.  Hmm.

Comment: You can expand the textarea as you need in most browsers like Chrome and Firefox. The text will show up as expected..Check this http://jsfiddle.net/h4mtsyh2/

Comment: It's not the size of the text area that's the problem.  The problem is that not all of the text is showing up.  I can't show an image, but here's what it looks like after hitting Submit:  Thesis is clear [next line] "Introduction  Well, there's supposed to be more to that line than simply Introduction.  Does this make sense?

Comment: It's working there.  Not quite sure why it's not working on mine.

Comment: You can copy the code directly from the fiddle and replace your code with this..It's the same code anyways!

Comment: I added some points to the code and now get what I mentioned.  The link works and helps, but I can get the whole thing to work.

Comment: Okay great..Accept the answer above or upvote it if it solves the problem!